# Why clicking on one dropdown list inside a dynamic form field automatically trigger another dropdown list from another form field

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a dynamic form field with a dropdown list where a user will be able to add and delete multiple contributors. Right now my code is able to add and delete multiple users, but whenever I add more than one contributor, then click on the dropdown list, the first dropdown list along with the selected dropdown list automatically gets triggered and they both start showing available user lists.

sample.component.html:

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Add Contributor</mat-label>
      <div formArrayName="contributors">

          <div *ngFor="let contributor of contributors.controls;
                       let contributorIndex=index"
                       [formGroupName]="contributorIndex">

            <mat-select formControlName="contributor">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.id">
                {{user.id + ' - ' + user.firstName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>

            <button type="button" class="deleteButton" (click)="deleteContributor(contributorIndex);" mat-mini-fab color="warn" aria-label="Delete contributor.">
              <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
        <button type="button" class="addButton" (click)="addContributor()" mat-mini-fab color="primary" aria-label="Add another contributor.">
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </mat-form-field>
```

sample.component.ts:

```
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  kpiForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddEditKpiDialogComponent>,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    this.kpiForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      contributors: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.group({contributor: ['', Validators.required]})]),
    });

   get contributors() {
    return this.kpiForm.get('contributors') as FormArray;
  }

  addContributor() {
    this.contributors.push(this.formBuilder.group({contributor: ''}));
  }

  deleteContributor(index) {
    if (this.contributors.length > 1) {
      this.contributors.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
}
```

Screenshots of the issue:

When I click on the third dropdown list the first one automatically gets triggered:

[image]

Added 3 contributors:

[image: Here 3 contributors were added]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `<mat-select>` should have its own `<mat-form-field>`.

Change the `<div>` with your `*ngFor` to be a `<mat-form-field>` (*maybe change your existing mat-form-field to div*):

```html
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let contributor of contributors.controls; let contributorIndex=index" [formGroupName]="contributorIndex">
```

Comment: this fixed the issue, thanks a lot, but why didn't it work the way I did before?